# Question about Evince pdf scrolling

Tags: gnome, pdf, scrolling, evince, zathura

I love Evince; along with Zathura for more minimal PDF viewing, it's my favorite document viewer.

I have a question about when I scroll using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. When I use the <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>K</kbd> to navigate it acts just like the up and down arrow keys would. When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, it scrolls the same amount but adds a smooth animation to it. I was wondering what this is as the same thing happens in Zathura.

I'd like to see if I can replicate this to also happen by default with <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> keys.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This came up randomly also in my experience. From a small research I found that in the "File option" menu (three horizontal lines 'hamburger' menu) and then > "Shortcuts", there are no entries for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowDown</kbd>.

Looking through the source code I firstly found a feature called "view scrolling" that's mapped with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(Arrows)</kbd>

At line 158-159 https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/blob/master/ChangeLog.pre-git#L158

Although that edit is very old (2009).

Hope to find more in further source code reading when I'll have more time. Any follow ups from your side during these two years? (Also saw the same post on Reddit, but no luck).